# port mapping -p 8080:8080 vs --net=host

Tags: docker

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip xz-utils git openssh-client curl python3 && apt-get upgrade -y && rm -rf /var/cache/apt

# Install Flutter
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter
ENV PATH="/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
RUN flutter channel master
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web
RUN flutter doctor -v

# Copy files to container and get dependencies
COPY . /usr/local/bin/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/app
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter build web

# Document the exposed port and start server
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/app/server/server.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/app/server/server.sh" ]
```

**Entrypoint `server.sh` file**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd build/web/
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

- I build an image - `docker build --network=host --tag image1 .`
- Then I try to run it:

  - `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image1` -- doesnt work. no error but just doesnt load
  - `docker run -d image1` -- doesnt work. no error but just doesnt load
  - `docker run -d --net=host image1` -- works !!

Why does `-p 8080:8080` not work whereas `--net=host` work ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access your app?  At port 8000 or 8080?  Your title and the command you posted doesn't seem to match.  Are you trying to map 8080 on your machine to 8080 in the app?  If so, you have a typo in your command.  Your command is mapping 8000 to 8080 and I'm guessing you're then trying to access it at localhost:8080 and encountering nothing.

I think it should just be `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image` and then you should be able access it at localhost:8080 just fine.

Comment: I have updated my question to remove confusion. I use 8080 (not 8000) and yet It doesnt work.

Comment: Hmmm...then I'm not sure this is a Docker issue then as your commands seem correct.  My only guess right now is if your app needs more than just port 8080 and you're not aware of it...?